# Create relationship between class and inheritor class with foreign key in EF

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, foreign-keys, relationship

I have this classes:

Adddress:

```
 public class Address
    {     

        public byte Address_Region { get; set; }
        public string Address_PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Address_Line { get; set; }
        public int City_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
    }
```

City:

```
    public class City
    {
        public int City_ID { get; set; } 
        public string City_Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
```

CityConfig:

```
 HasKey(c => c.City_ID);
            Property(c => c.City_ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(c => c.City_Name).HasMaxLength(30);
            HasMany(c => c.Addresses).WithRequired(a => a.City).HasForeignKey(a=>a.City_ID);
```

and School:

```
public class School:Address
    {
        public School() { }
        public int School_ID { get; set; }
        public string School_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

---

in DBMOdelContext:

```
public virtual DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
```

and in ModelBuilder:

```
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CityConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SchoolConfig());
```

---

and Error:

System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: 'One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

### SchoolContextModel.Models.ModelLayers.Address: : EntityType 'Address' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Addresses: EntityType: EntitySet 'Addresses' is based on type 'Address' that has no keys defined.
'

I Define City_ID in class Address as PrimaryKEy in Address Config:
HasKey(c => c.City_ID);

then in and in ModelBuilder add:
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SchoolConfig());

Then Error:

**City_Addresses_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'City_Addresses_Target' in relationship 'City_Addresses'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.**

---

How Can i Solve It??? tanx guys

Comment: Like the error says: "EntityType 'Address' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType."

Comment: I Define City_ID in class Address as PrimaryKEy in Address Config:
HasKey(c => c.City_ID);

 then in and in ModelBuilder add: modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SchoolConfig());

Then Error:

City_Addresses_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'City_Addresses_Target' in relationship 'City_Addresses'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

Comment: Which is telling you that City_ID is not a valid key for Address.  It needs its own key if it's 1-Many with City.

Comment: The school class has a primary key and inherits from the address class.
The address class has a one-to-many relationship with the city class.
When defining the primary key for the address, because the school class also has a primary key, it gives an error.
If I don't define it, it still gives an error.

Comment: If School inherits from Address it should not have its own primary key.  Also probably  School should not inherit from Address.  A School "has an" address.  Not a School "is an" Address.

Comment: If the school does not have a primary key, it will give an error and the school table will not be created. hooom ?